# Python Pandas: Is There a Faster Way to Split and Recombine a DataFrame based on criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I want to group this DataFrame based on a particular column "ContactID", but if the group's column "PaymentType" doesn't include a particular value, then I want to remove the entire group from the DataFrame.

I have something like this:

```
UniqueID = data.drop_duplicates('ContactID')['ContactID'].tolist()
OnlyRefinance=[]
for i in UniqueID:
    splits = data[data['ContactID']==i].reset_index(drop=True)
    if any(splits['PaymentType']==160):
        OnlyRefinance.append(splits)
OnlyRefinance = pd.concat(OnlyRefinance)
```

This works but it's VERY slow and I was wondering if there was a faster way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option you can use `groupby.filter`:

```
data.groupby("ContactID").filter(lambda g: (g.PaymentType == 160).any())
```

This will only keep groups whose *PaymentType* contains 160.

Comment: @EdChum Thank you.

Comment: Thanks so much Psidom. This is perfect!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this easier by doing:

```
to_drop = data.loc[data['PaymentType'] == 160, 'ContactID'].unique()
data[~data['ContactID'].isin(to_drop)]
```

So first filter out all rows where the condition isn't met and get the unique contact ids we want to drop

then pass these to `isin` and invert the mask using `~` this will remove all rows where the ContactID is in this array

Comment: Thanks EdChum! This is a great solution